# How to set a font family with pandoc?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, pandoc, markdown

I have some reports written in MultiMarkDown and want to convert them to pdf (via xelatex) with pandoc. As I am in an professional environment, a certain font-family is mandatory. The fonts are sitting right in the windows/fonts folder, named `font-regular.otf`, `font-italic.otf` and so on.

I know about the command line switch `-V mainfont:font-regular.otf` and I am able to switch font with it, but that only sets the regular font. I can do the run for a `.tex` instead of a `.pdf` and edit the file manualy like

```
\setmainfont[
BoldFont = Font-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Font-Italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont = Font-BoldItalic.otf
]{Font-Regular.otf}
```

But that is cumbersome, since it is additional work for each document to be converted.

Is there a way to:

- easily create a "font-family" that I can pass, or
- pass the fout `.otf` via command line (and therefore via script or batch)

Comment: You want to create a custom template that contains the font definitions you need. See: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**YAML header**

```yaml
---
mainfont: Font-Regular.otf
mainfontoptions:
- BoldFont=Font-Bold.otf
- ItalicFont=Font-Italic.otf
- BoldItalicFont=Font-BoldItalic.otf
---
```

**command line**

```bash
$ pandoc in.md --pdf-engine=xelatex \
         -V 'mainfont:Font-Regular.otf' \
         -V 'mainfontoptions:BoldFont=Font-Bold.otf, ItalicFont=Font-Italic.otf, BoldItalicFont=Font-BoldItalic.otf'
         -o out.pdf
```

---

Since my answer to the original question, a lot has changed. So here is an update on how to set fonts with pandoc. There are several ways to change the font in `pandoc` and they are quite well [documented](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex) nowadays. Here is a brief overview:

## 1. Changing fonts for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX:

You can specify any font on your system that can be used with [`fontspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)

In the YAML header of your markdown file, set the variables like this for XeLaTeX:

```yaml
---
mainfont: DejaVuSerif.ttf
sansfont: DejaVuSans.ttf
monofont: DejaVuSansMono.ttf 
mathfont: texgyredejavu-math.otf 
---
```

or, for LuaLaTex:

```yaml
---
mainfont: DejaVuSerif
sansfont: DejaVuSans
monofont: DejaVuSansMono
mathfont: TeXGyreDejaVuMath-Regular
---
```

If you need more fine grained control, you can specify options:

```yaml
---
mainfont: DejaVuSerif
mainfontoptions:
- Extension=.ttf
- UprightFont=*
- BoldFont=*-Bold
- ItalicFont=*-Italic
- BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic
---
```

Call pandoc with `--pdf-engine` set to `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```bash
$ pandoc in.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o out.pdf
```

You can also set the fonts on the command line:

```bash
$ pandoc in.md --pdf-engine=xelatex \
         -V 'mainfont:DejaVuSerif.ttf' \
         -V 'sansfont:DejaVuSans.ttf' \
         -V 'monofont:DejaVuSansMono.ttf' \
         -V 'mathfont:texgyredejavu-math.otf' \
         -o out.pdf
```

or

```bash
$ pandoc in.md --pdf-engine=lualatex \
         -V 'mainfont:DejaVuSerif' \
         -V 'sansfont:DejaVuSans' \
         -V 'monofont:DejaVuSansMono' \
         -V 'mathfont:TeXGyreDejaVuMath-Regular' \
         -o out.pdf
```

And again, with options:

```bash
$ pandoc in.md --pdf-engine=xelatex \
         -V 'mainfont:DejaVuSerif' \
         -V 'mainfontoptions:Extension=.ttf, UprightFont=*, BoldFont=*-Bold, ItalicFont=*-Italic, BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic' \
         -V 'sansfont:DejaVuSans.ttf' \
         -V 'monofont:DejaVuSansMono.ttf' \
         -V 'mathfont:texgyredejavu-math.otf' \
         -o out.pdf
```

Note, that `xelatex` wants the filename, while `lualatex` is content with the fontfamily name. You can use [otfinfo](http://www.lcdf.org/type/otfinfo.1.html) to get more information on names and features of the font you are going to use.

[image: Example]

## 2. Change the template

Some packages like `dejavu-otf` or `libertinus-otf` do the fontspec setup for you, but you have to modify the template in order for them to work.

Get the default template and save it to some file:

```bash
$ pandoc -D latex > template.latex
```

Open the file and remove all the font configuration code and replace it with, e.g.:

```latex
\usepackage{dejavu-otf}
```

## 3. Setting the `fontfamily` for pdflatex

If you are using `pdflatex`, you can use:

```yaml
---
fontfamily: dejavu
---
```

or

```bash
$ pandoc in.md --pdf-engine=pdflatex \ 
         -V 'fontfamily:dejavu' \
         -o demo.pdf
```

The option `fontfamily` tries to load a package with the specified name. This usually applies for Type 1 fonts and `pdflatex` but there are also packages that use `fontspec` internally when called from `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

## 4. Setting the font for context

```yaml
---
mainfont: DejaVuSerif
sansfont: DejaVuSans
monofont: DejaVuSansMono
mathfont: TeXGyreDejaVuMath
---
```

or

```bash
$ pandoc in.md --pdf-engine=context \
         -V 'mainfont:DejaVuSerif' \
         -V 'sansfont:DejaVuSans' \
         -V 'monofont:DejaVuSansMono' \
         -V 'mathfont:TeXGyreDejaVuMath' \
         -o out.odf
```

---

Comment: with pandoc 1.19.2.4  , I had to use `--latex-engine` instead of `--pdf-engine`

Comment: @zm0 Right, old versions of pandoc (<2.0) use that flag. With newer versions you can also use other programs beside latex to generate pdfs. See: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--pdf-engine and https://pandoc.org/changelog.txt

Comment: Is there not any way to do this without XeLaTeX/LuaTeX?

Answer (score 5):

I just saw this while looking for how to set the heading font using pandoc -> xelatex

It is possible to set the mainfont and mainfont options using metadata settings. For example, your configuration would look like this:

```
mainfont: Font-Regular.otf
mainfontoptions: BoldFont=Font-Bold.otf
mainfontoptions: ItalicFont=Font-Italic.otf
mainfontoptions: BoldItalicFont=Font-BoldItalic.otf
```

You can also use the full names of the fonts. Here is how I setup Gentium Basic as my main font:

```
mainfont: Gentium Basic
mainfontoptions: BoldFont=Gentium Basic Bold
mainfontoptions: ItalicFont=Gentium Basic Italic
mainfontoptions: BoldItalicFont=Gentium Basic Bold Italic
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, but you need to set the `mainfontoptions` at once or else only the last one will be taken.

Answer (score 2):

Get the default `tex` template from pandoc by running `pandoc -D latex` and then add the font definitions you want to the document. save as `my-font.latex`. Then run pandoc with the switch `--template=my-font`.