# How to exclude package when converting md to tex with pandoc

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I need to use `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}`. Pandoc default is `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

My YAML header in md file is

```
---
title: My tytle
author: Me
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
---
```

When I compile md file, I have both T1 and T2A packages.
Is it possible to exclude T1 package, please?

I try

```
---
title: My tytle
author: Me
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
header-excludes:
  - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
---
```

but it not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc defines a variable for fontenc in the default template, that means that you can specify the encoding in the YAML-header directly:

```
---
title: My tytle
author: Me
fontenc: T2A
---
```

Comment: Btw. you can use `pandoc -D latex` to print the default latex template to check what `pandoc` is actually doing, instead of guessing...

Comment: Thank you. It works for T2A. But I still need to remove `\usepackage{lmodern}` (I use Cyrillic fonts). I can comment it in tex file, but it will be nice if I can remove it from YAML header in md file.

Comment: This site works on a one question at a time basis, so please mark my answer as accepted. How to change fonts has already been answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234796/29873 and it is well documented in the user's guide: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex