# change pandoc font for paragraph

Tags: fonts, xetex, pandoc

I am trying to change the fontfamily for a paragraph using markdown and pandoc with xetex. I couldn't find references to this online.

I am currently setting my main font using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234796/35056) answer:

```yaml
---
mainfont: DejaVuSerif.ttf
sansfont: DejaVuSans.ttf
monofont: DejaVuSansMono.ttf 
mathfont: texgyredejavu-math.otf 
---
```

I am looking for this pseudocode

```markdown
# Chapter 1

{\setFontFamily{DejaVu} %%%% EDIT: \setFontFamily is a name example. I don't know if it exists.%%%%

paragraph 1
}

{\setFontFamily{merriweather}
paragraph 2
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where did you find `\setFontFamily`? `fontspec` provides `\setfontfamily` which is used completely different

Comment: sorry, I probably didn't put it clear enough. I said it was pseudocode so the intention was clear, but I have no clue which command can be used. I made up `\setFontFamily`. I will try to edit the question. Sorry once again